# Matching different name formats

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have two data files I need to match:

- The first has Names, Dates, and Hours worked. The names on this are formatted last, first (nickname). eg, `Smith, John (John)`.
- The second has only names and dates, and needs the hours filled in from the first, if they are listed. This one has a name format of first and maybe middle initial, plus last, as one string. eg, `JSMITH` or `JDSMITH`.

I realize if more than one person has the same last name it might be problematic, but is there a way to compare and pull these hours with a formula, or does this have to be a manual process?

Some of these are upwards of 1500 lines. If possible, I'd like to do this via formula, as no one else in the office knows any VBA. If VBA is the only way, I'll try to figure out a way to make it user friendly.

Comment: Yes, vba may help you.  Check the following article about "user defined function" : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: You should also be able to do this with an Excel formula (no VBA).  `VLOOKUP`, `LEFT`, `FIND` and `MID` should give you what you need.  Check out the Excel help or google these for some pointers!

Comment: I thought this initially, but there are two issues I haven't been able to work past with this approach. First, if I do a LEFT or RIGHT formula, I have to dictate how many characters to look for. Assuming I could make this dynamic, which I'm not sure how to do, I still would have to tell it where to stop on the second file which may or may not have a middle initial.

Comment: VBA is very capable of these comparisions. I think you should indeed start with making a UDF, like @Seb suggested, then come back here with some code you have, so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Vlookups, or better yet a Sumproduct function? There's a great introduction here which I've used extensively:

http://www.accountingweb.com/topic/excel/some-unlikely-uses-sumproduct

To match name, search for the following conditions being met:
First character of first name in file 1 is equal to first character of whole name in file 2;
Surname in file 2 is equal to all but first (or all but first two) character(s) of whole name in file 2.

Start with something like: (in sheet2)

```
Left('[file1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1) = Left(A1)
```

Comment: I did think about some sort of sumproduct, but my issue with that is getting the names narrowed down to something that is an exact match. If I can find a way to get the names to be equivalent, I could use the sumproduct with name and date to find hours.

Comment: Try something like if(or(right([cell],5)=target,right([cell],4) = target,,,) - ie, check both cases (assuming a middle initial plus surname isn't equal to someone else's surname!